# How can a maven build fail when certain dependencies are present?

Tags: java, maven

In one of my POM's a dependency had a wrong scope.
While running the application, this (test) dependency was the cause of an OutOfMemoryError.

I would like to prevent this by adding a plugin that iterates over all (including transitive) dependencies and verify the occurrence of a certain pattern, like an artifactId containing "test".

How can I filter all dependencies and fail the build when a certain pattern appears?

**After dan1st answer, this solution fits my current needs:**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>enforce-banned-dependencies</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <rules>
                    <bannedDependencies>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>*:*-test</exclude>
                            <exclude>*:test-*</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </bannedDependencies>
                </rules>
                <fail>true</fail>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: you should be careful to do such things. it sounds logical, but good luck in building a project with a dependency on a library with artifact-id "attest-verifier"

Comment: fair point, will have to handle that problem when it occurs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maven enforcer plugin [allows to ban dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/bannedDependencies.html):

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>enforce-banned-dependencies</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <rules>
                <bannedDependencies>
                <searchTransitive>true</searchTransitive>
                <message>Dependency not allowed!</message>
                  <excludes>
                    <!-- do one of the following: --> 
                    <exclude>all.dependencies.with.this.group.id.are.banned</exclude>
                    <exclude>group.id-to-ban:artifact-id-of-artifact-to-ban</exclude>
                    <exclude>group.id-to-ban:artifact-id-of-artifact-to-ban:versiontoban</exclude>
                    <!-- wildcards with '*' are also allowed -->
                  
                </bannedDependencies>
              </rules>
              <fail>true</fail>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: Aha, I thought I used a plugin in the past for something similar but couldn't remember the name. I'll explore this option

Answer (score 0):

You can customize maven-enforcer to include your own rule which implements your specific use case (text pattern match). For example take a look [here](https://github.com/gaol/version-maven-enforcer-rule).